# Ensure parenthesis are balanced?

Tags: java

I am tasked to create a function that checks if a number of small "(" and big "[" parentheses and closes properly. For example...

```
(()) [] ([])[(())]
```

...is correct, but...

```
() [(])
```

...is incorrect.

Any advice on how to start approaching this problem? The use of recursive functions is prohibited.

---

This is what I have so far:

```
{
    int nr_ap_x = 0; // fie x - "("
    int nr_ap_y = 0; // fie y - ")"
    boolean corect = true;

    for (int i=0; i < sir.length; i++)
    {
        if (sir[i].compareTo("(") == 0) nr_ap_x++;
        else
            if (sir[i].compareTo(")") == 0) nr_ap_y++;
        if (nr_ap_x < nr_ap_y) corect = false;
    }
    if (nr_ap_x != nr_ap_y) corect = false;
    if (corect) System.out.println("Parantezele sunt inchise corect ! ");
    else System.out.println("Parantezele NU sunt inchise corect ! ");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

General outline of how to do this (assuming you have an array of strings each containing a parenthesis):

- Create a stack which contains strings.
- For each "(" or "[", push onto the stack.
- For each ")" or "]", check if the top of the stack matches the type of parenthesis.

  - If it does, discard the top of the stack.
  - Otherwise, the parenthesis are mismatched.

If you have a non empty stack once all your strings run out, you also have mismatched parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: keep a data structure containing the opening glyphs, and use and update it when a closing glyph appear.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that's done with recursion can also be done with iteration.  If you already know how to do it recursively then map it to a while loop. This is explained in [Replace Recursion with Iteration](http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceRecursionWithIteration.html).

Comment: I gave a +1. However, the article only discusses recursion that is tail-call optimizable, which is a far more specific case than emulating recursion with a stack.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a deterministic finite automaton - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite-state_machine